# Remove specific folders with condition(s) using a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm a newbie at batch scripting and couldn't figure out how to write up a batch file removing specific folders with conditions in **c:\root**.

**Conditions:**

1. If the folder names are other than "Paul", "Mike", "Daniel" and
   "Pierre"
2. If the folder does not have a sub-folder or file

**Action:**

Delete that folder.

In my example, **c:\root\test1** should be deleted with this batch file.

> c:\root
>
> c:\root\Paul
>
> c:\root\Mike
>
> c:\root\Mike\assignment
>
> c:\root\Mike\assignment\assignment1.txt
>
> c:\root\Daniel
>
> c:\root\Daniel\exam
>
> c:\root\Pierre
>
> c:\root\Pierre\quiz.txt
>
> c:\root\test1
>
> c:\root\test2
>
> c:\root\test2\test2.txt

Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Thank you very much.

Comment: See the `if` and `for` commands to start. `if /?` and `for /?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with this batch to test if the size of the folder equal to `0` (`size=0`) then we can remove it !

Just give a try for this code and if you get the output as you expected, just get rid of the `echo`

```
@echo off
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
set "folder=%~1"
if not defined folder set "folder=%cd%"
for /d %%a in ("%folder%\*") do (
    set "size=0"
    for /f "tokens=3,5" %%b in ('dir /-c /a /w /s "%%~fa\*" 2^>nul ^| findstr /b /c:"  "') do if "%%~c"=="" set "size=%%~b"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
      If "!size!"=="0" Echo RD "%%~na"
    endlocal
    )
endlocal
pause
exit
```